# Is there a way to sum 1 to a column value without retrieving the value via a query first?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm checking to see if a value already exists in the DB, if it does I want to just update the `last_date` as well as up the count (`visit_num`) by 1. I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to do that than by running a query to retrieve the current number and then doing `++`. This is what I currently have (without retrieving the column).

```
function subscribe($visit_num, $email, $last_visit_date){

$sql = 'SELECT 1 from `visits` WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->fetchColumn()){
            $totalVisits = /*Somehow retrieve the current count*/ + $visit_num;

            $query = "UPDATE `visits` SET
                        `visit_num`=:visit_num,
                        `last_visit_date`=:last_visit_date
                    WHERE
                        `email` = :email";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

            // bind values
            $stmt->bindParam(":visit_num", $totalVisits);
            $stmt->bindParam(":last_visit_date", $last_visit_date);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
            $res = $stmt->execute();

            if($res){
                $arr = array('message' => 'Added');
                echo json_encode($arr);
            }else{
                $arr = array('message' => "Error");
                echo json_encode($arr);
            }
}
```

I can just do (previous to this) a "`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'visits' WHERE 'email' = '$email'"` and add it but I'm not sure whether that's the best approach or if there's something better.

Comment: Why do you need the `SELECT` at all? You can always update with `visit_num = visit_num + 1` or some such. The `UPDATE` has a `WHERE` clause, so will only update rows that match. It returns the number of rows updated, so you can still implement the remainder of the logic based on whether it returns 0 or something more.

Comment: @TedHopp I think the point was to return the totalvisits from the select. Although, unless you need to display the totalvisits you could simply add one to the existing visit_num value (without a select as you said). Unless there is a need to add a variable amount.

Comment: @JacobH - That's exactly my point. You can just do arithmetic on columns within the `UPDATE` and don't need to retrieve the value at all. (At least as far as I can tell from OP's code and problem description.)

Comment: Yes, we're in agreement. Just clarifying what I thought they were *trying* to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in one statement:

```
UPDATE `visits` SET
   `visit_num`=`visit_num` + 1,
   `last_visit_date`=CURDATE()
WHERE
   `email` = :email";
```

If you need to know the number of visits for display or downstream logic in your application, then run the separate select, but that's an unrelated use case. Obviously you can switch out what you need to here, like changing the `CURDATE()` to your incoming parameter for this function.

In the event that this email doesn't exist in the table and you want to perform an INSERT where the UPDATE would fail, you can still do this in one SQL Statement using [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I was not aware I could do this @JNevill, thank you!